# How to transfer c and python code binary to bin

Tags: python, binary, debian-installer

I have created a project in c and python for that i have created lot of files in both languages when compilation done it create single `a.out` for all c files and the c file calls to `*.py`files from `a.out`

My question is how to transfer that files in bin so we can access directly as command or as graphical icon from search option?

Or is there any way to create Debian package of the whole system?

Finally i have make a link of `a.out` on desktop but some functionality not work and core dump occur

Help me out to solve this problem !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move them to `~/.bin` (create if it does not exist). Then add them to `$PATH` by adding the following line to `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.bin/
```

and then, after restarting the terminal, you should be able to run it directly:

```
$ a.out
```

But they won't show up in the graphical search menu. To do *that*, create a `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=YourApp
Comment=Description of YourApp
Exec=sh -c '~/.bin/a.out'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true 
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

and save it at `~/.local/share/applications/YourApp.desktop`